# Privacy preserving functions vs secure multi-party computation

Tags: multiparty-computation

As we all know, secure multi-party computation allows us to run a certain computation/function on private inputs contributed by different parties (that do not necessarily trust each other). The security guarantee of an MPC is that parties learn nothing beyond the computation result.

*However, MPC does not deal with the question of whether the function (output) itself reveals much information about the inputs.*

---

**Question**: Is there any class of functions that ensures an adversary (given the output) cannot learn anything about the honest parties inputs?

Comment: I think one-way functions should have the property you are looking for